# What are 'weak' forms of Urysohn's lemma, which do not require choice?

Tags: general-topology, axiom-of-choice

Reference: http://web.mat.bham.ac.uk/C.Good/research/pdfs/horror.pdf

It is well known that the original proof of Urysohn's lemma uses a choice principle. (DC)

What are weak forms of the Urysohn's lemma that don't require choice? For example, one is in the link. ($\text{ Second Countable } + \text{ Regular } \Rightarrow \text{ Urysohn's lemma }$)

I also saw somewhere (I don't remember) that Urysohn's Lemma is provable without choice if it is metric space. (Edit; Now I remember. It was an exercise on PMA, using Hausdorff distance)

Comment: I am fairly sure that the arguments I've seen for 2nd countable + regular => urysohn's lemma required choice.

Comment: @gnometorule Are you even sure for the argument in the link? Otherwise i'm going to spend my whole day to check it.

Comment: For metric spaces and disjoint non-empty closed subsets $A$ and $B$ you can just write $f(x) = \frac{d(x,A)}{d(x,A)+d(x,B)}$ to get a function $f$ which is $0$ on $A$ and $1$ on $B$. Is that what you mean by alluding to [Hausdorff distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance) (which is something else)?

Comment: @Martin Yes, exactly. How do i call $d(x,A)$ then?

Comment: It's usually called the distance of $x$ to $A$ or something to that effect.

Comment: @gnometorule I just spent my whole day to read the argument and whole references in the link related to Urysohn's Lemma, and it works fine without any choice! And more surprisingly, "If  $X$ is a regular Hausdorff and second countable and $A,B$ are disjoint closed subsets, there exists a 'uniquely' defined continuous function $f:X\rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $f(A)\subset\{0\}$ and $f(B)\subset\{1\}$" is true in ZF

Comment: However, I'm not sure Urysohn's lemma holds for locally compact space. Is it provable?

Comment: @Katlus: Interesting. I had seen two proofs (probably the most standard), and from memory they both used choice. Also, the abstract of the paper seemed vague in the matter. From the abstract, it didnt seem clear they wouldn't need choice - but maybe that was me reading this wrong, or it was phrased not as clear as it could have been.